# Which class to call DAL from?

Tags: c#, class-design

```
public class Car
{
    public int ID { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // ?? Do I need these or is it better to have Car just contain properties?
    Add();
    Delete();
}

public static class CarDatabaseAccess
{
    public void AddCar(Car c);
    public void DeleteCar(Car c);
    public List<Car> RetrieveCars();
}
```

With the object setup above, what's the correct way to delete a Car? I basically have two options

```
public void DeleteButton_Click(...)
{
    var car = listView.SelectedItem as Car;
    CarDatabaseAccess.DeleteCar(car);

    // or

    var car = listView.SelectedItem as Car;
    car.Delete();
}
```

The Database Access Layer calls stored procedures so I can't switch to Entity or anything like that.

I should note there are 100s of objects that will need a DatabaseAccess class so setting up Interfaces for DatabaseAccess layer (for Dependency Injection testing) will not be feasable in the time frame that I have

Comment: Well if you had `Car.Delete` what would the implmentation look like? Most likely it would be `CarDatabaseAccess.DeleteCar(this);`, at that point you are writing redundant code and DeleteButton_Click could have just passed the class in.

Answer (score 2):

You basically have a repository pattern here. Take the operations out of Car, and use CarDatabaseAccess which should be an Interface so it is testable.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the second approach, because you are calling an instance method and this makes it testable. Using a library like [FakeItEasy](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy) you could intercept the second `Delete()` method and to test the scenario. In the first instance, you can't intercept or test the static method call.

```
var car = listView.SelectedItem as Car;
car.Delete();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're somewhat mixing two approaches. The first one, when you include Add/Delete/... methods directly in your object, it's called `Active record pattern`. The second one is when you create a separate class to handle these actions, that's called `Repository pattern`. There's really no reason to mix these two and you really shouldn't, at least not like this.

Pick which one you like more, it doesn't really matter. Try to be consistent though.